# hooks didn't load in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

I'm new in codeigniter, I want 2 page with the name of "login" and "admin"
i use hook and session to detect user is logged in or not, but unfortunately hook didn't load (Call) at all.
any idea?
**My controller :**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
    }


    public function index(){

    }
}
```

**My hook :**

```
<?php  if ( !defined( 'BASEPATH' ) ) exit( 'No direct script access allowed' );

class Auth_hook {

    protected $CI;

    public function __construct() {
      $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function index(){
      print_r("hello!!");
      }
    }
}
?>
```

**EDIT:** And finally `hooks.php` :

```
$hooks['pre_controller']=array(
    'class'=>'Auth_hook',
    'function'=>'index',
    'filename'=>'Auth_hook.php',
    'filepath'=>'hooks'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$hook['pre_controller']
```

Instead of this :

```
$hooks['pre_controller']
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check code manual [hooks](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html)?

application/config/hooks.php:

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
                                'class'    => '',
                                'function' => 'MY_FUNCTION',
                                'filename' => 'MY_CLASS.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks',
                                'params'   => ''
                                );
```

application/hooks/MY_CLASS.php:

```
<?php    
function Myfunction(){
    echo "HOOK PROBLEM .. !!";
    die;
}
?>
```

For that, I move into this page and get a 'HOOK PROBLEM .. !!'.

**EDIT:**

Your code is doing what you want. You need to check that the login before you do any kind of redirect.

```
If (user is not logged in) {
    If (Current route is not a login page) {
        Redirect user to login page
    }
}
```

Comment: @SyedNoman your link is a old out of date one ellislab does not deal with CI any more use links from here if you can.http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: Thank u for correcting me. Its helpful for me and ofcourse someone as well.

Comment: @SyedNoman you didn't get what my mean is, the hook never called and page showed blank